# Describe the conjugacy classes of UT(3,Zp)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How can all the conjugacy classes of UT(3,Zp) be described, if UT(3,Zp) is a unitriangular matrix group so its members look like $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 0 & 1 & a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $ , $a_{12},a_{13},a_{23} \in \mathbf{Zp}$, $\mathbf{Zp}$ is a сyclic field and p is a prime number?

Comment: Should there be a $1$ in the lower-right entry?

Comment: Also, shouldn't $\Bbb Z_p$ be a *field*, rather than a group?

Comment: Thats right, my mistake

Comment: My mistake; apparently $\Bbb Z_n$ is allowed to simply be a ring rather than a field (that is, even if $n$ isn't prime, this set of matrices forms a group).  However, I assume that the $p$ here means that $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** if $a$ has the form
$$
a = \pmatrix{1&a_1&a_3\\&1&a_2\\&&1}
$$
then the elements of the conjugacy class of $a$ are given by
$$
\pmatrix{1&a_1&a_3 + a_2j - a_1 k\\&1&a_2\\&&1}
$$
where $j,k \in \Bbb Z_p$.

If you get stuck again, it will help to know that this group is also referred to as the *finite Heisenberg group*.